Использование excel файлов для генерации представлений в ASP проекте
Есть портал информационно-аналитической системы мониторинга, на платформе .NET.
Все страницы выглядят как набор таблиц.

Каждой ячейке присвоен id в атрибуте data, чтобы отображать значение из БД.
data-param-id="1234"
Таблицы могут быть большие. ~100 строк и более.
Сейчас все таблицы сверстаны в cshtml. Соответственно нужно у каждой ячейки в ручную прописать все атрибуты. Из за чего их создавать и редактировать не очень удобно.
Я подумал, почему бы не использовать для рисования таблиц Excel, а затем для представлений генерировать таблицы из файлов. То есть использовать excel файлы как конфигурационные. Можно даже использовать атрибуты в ячейках \атрибут{значение}

Но мне, не очень нравится, что нужно хранить excel файлы в проекте. Хотя создавать таблицы так намного быстрее чем писать html на 1500-2000 строк кода из бесконечных tr td с colspan rowspan.
Можно ли так делать, с точки зрения архитектуры проекта? Коллега сказал, что так не понятно, лишние файлы с проектом хранятся и надо писать в html. Но ведь файлы конфигурации тоже с проектом хранятся.
p.s. Можно даже сохранить excel файл в xml и его закинуть в БД. Тогда даже файлов с проектом не будет.
